# Undefined mapState component when I call in created() hook

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When I try to do that I have an error alert is undefined

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(['rol'])
},
created() {
 alert(this.rol)
}
```

but when I try in the template rol = 1 and it's working

```
<template>
  {{rol}}
</template>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong please help me

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems to be incorrect. Try the following:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(['rol'])
},
created () {
 alert(this.rol)
}
```

**update:**

The actual solution was to set a timeout before the alert (see below comment by  Joao Paulo).

The state and the Vuex store can already be accessed in the `created()` hook. See  also: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: In general it is possible to access the computed properties in the `created` hook. See also: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: Can you check your console logs and provide file of your `Vuex` store

Comment: if i put on created console.log(this.$store.state) i can show the data but i put console.log(this.$store.state.rol) is undefined

Comment: So basically if you write `const mappedState = this.$store.state` and `console.log('rol', mappedState.rol)` you can log it?

Comment: Hi Simon, try alert the value with some setTimeout, maybe you are printing the value before its getting set. I recommend you to use the vuejs chrome extension, it shows you exactly how your state looks like.

Comment: i added two photos